# ruby on rails cant JavaScript not loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I use [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) with rails 4.0.2,

trail github examples.. actually working perfectly when load specific url.

but using menu-bar, not JavaScript is not working.

situation...

I connect //localhost:3000 , next click menu after change url : //localhost:3000/trip

but not showing google map.

then I refresh browser, I can show google map.

I want know this happen.. Can I control loading JavaScript?

Comment: It could be because of turbolinks. If you dont need it, you can just remove `gem 'turbolinks'` line from your Gemfile. Or Do this for any particular link `= link_to('trip', trip_path, 'data-no-turbolink' => true) `

Comment: thanks Santosh. perfect works

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because of turbolinks. If you dont need it, you can just remove `gem 'turbolinks'` line from your `Gemfile.`

Or do this for any particular `link = link_to('trip', trip_path, 'data-no-turbolink' => true)`